# Generator object with yield

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have found the below piece of code on the internet, with the actual `output`

```
def countdown(start):
   print start
   if start == 0:
      yield 0
   else:
      yield countdown(start -1)

g = countdown(3)
g.next()
g.next()
```

the output of the code is

`3 
StopIteration`

Can anyone break this code down for me, Is `next()` skipping the sequence of the generator? I can't seem to understand the flow here

Comment: possible duplicate of [python yield and stopiteration in one loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784934/python-yield-and-stopiteration-in-one-loop)

Comment: What do you expect `yield countdown(start - 1)` to do?

Comment: A link to the function: http://www.usrsb.in/Bouncing-Python-s-Generators-With-A-Trampoline.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you found **that** code on the internet. You seem to be missing the entire point of [that blog post](http://www.usrsb.in/Bouncing-Python-s-Generators-With-A-Trampoline.html), and if you use `g = g.next()` instead of `g.next()` like it's shown there, then it makes sense and it works.

But to answer your question, why it goes wrong the way it goes wrong when you do it like you did:

`countdown` yields exactly one thing, either 0 or another generator. `g.next()` fetches that one thing, and since you don't do anything with it, it's lost. And then, since `g` is still the original generator, and it already gave you the one thing it had to give, you get that `StopIteration` when you ask it for a second thing.

If instead you assign that second generator back to `g` like you should, then you can ask *that* generator to give you *its* one item. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
def countdown(start):
  if start >= 0:
    yield start
    for i in countdown(start -1):
      yield i

g = countdown(3)
g.next()  #3
g.next()  #2
g.next()  #1
g.next()  #0
g.next()  #StopIteration
```

**problem**

`yield countdown(start -1)` return a generator and iteration then stop

Comment: Actually i did not write the code, I found it on the internet with the answer `3 StopIteration`, so just wanted to understand the flow of the code

Comment: @Bad_Coder `3` is printed in first instruction, as `start` isn't equal to 3 return `countdown(start -1)` and stop iteration

Comment: @Bad_Coder Can you give us the link?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: http://www.usrsb.in/Bouncing-Python-s-Generators-With-A-Trampoline.html

Comment: @wwii Yeah, thanks, I found it as well (easier than I had thought) and wrote an answer myself.